# Why is Spring Boot not reading from default application.properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have created a brand new project with spring boot initializr but it doesn't seem to be reading application.properties (in src\main\resources). No matter what level I set my log level to, I don't see a change in the output. Any Idea why it's not reading it?

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.9.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.cookbook'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

[image]

Comment: logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG applies DEBUG level for packages 
org.springframework.web* If you need to see from DEBUG logs from your application packages (com.cookbook*) set logging.level.com.cookbook=DEBUG

Comment: The console logs. The logs display INFO level logs even when I have DEBUG or ERROR in the properties file.

Comment: I've tried logging.level.org.springframework and logging.level.com.cookbook as well but neither show the DEBUG logs when spring starts. It also doesn't seem to be reading my H2Database properties when I add them in.

Comment: Please show ASCII art of your entire project directory tree.

Comment: Is the behavior consistent when invoked via command line? (Try doing ```gradle bootRun```.) Just to rule out problems with the IDE

Comment: Hmm... yup it seems to be the IDE. It runs fine from command line. Any idea what settings in Intellij would cause this?

Comment: I run an older version of IntelliJ for which Gradle support is poor. You could try switching to maven instead. It has great support for it in my view.

Comment: Did you add resources folder after  project creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by closing intellij then deleting .gradle folder then re-importing resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have spring.profiles set in application.properties.  If yes remove it, it will use the default properties file.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but if youusing Intellij-Idea then set the "**-Dlogging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG**" in VM Options instead of putting the option in application.properties file.